# Какую базу данных выбрать для большого количества записей под ASP NET?

Tags: sql, база-данных, веб-программирование, asp.net

Есть сущность сообщение (заголовок, дата создания, тело и т.п) у сообщения есть связь с сущностью автор как один ко многим. Необходимо вставлять большое количество (bulk insert) новых сообщений и авторов в базу, примерно 15 тыс за раз. Получать сообщения и авторов нужно не много (штук по 20 за раз). Какую базу использовать под ASP NET MVC для этой задачи?

Comment: Oracle, postgres, mysql, SQLLite

Comment: asp - чики как правило на ms sql пишут

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `MS SQL`, ведь в **.NET** для него прямо "*из коробки*" предоставлются провайдеры и удобное API для работы с **ORM** (читай - *Entity Framework*), а использование **ORM**, с свою очередь, значительно упростит работу с БД из кода приложения, особенно в Вашем случае, если проект пишете с нуля (подход *code first* значительно упростит жизнь и избавит от необходимости проектировать БД и писать скрипты самому). Единственный момент, на который следует обратить дополнительное внимание - правильный выбор столбцов в таблицах, по которым нужно построить индексы (за исключением кластеризованных). Тут всё зависит от того, по каким полям следует осуществлять поиск для вывода в интерфейс пользователя. Возможно, потребуется создать хранимые процедуры, которые значительно ускорят выполнение сложных поисковых запросов, если в БД будет храниться большое количество записей. Опять же, с индексами не стоит переусердствовать (не стоит индексировать сразу все поля), т.к. это значительно замедлит процесс вставки больших данных.

Кратко говоря, на Вашем месте я бы выбрал MS SQL по следующим причинам:

1. Инструменты для работы с ORM "из коробки" без использования сторонних бибилиотек и пакетов (NUGET: Install-Package EntityFramework)
2. Подход Code First (Генерация БД из прямо из классов сущностей)
3. Возможность включения миграций (внесение изменений в БД на основании изменений в сущностях)
4. Возможность использования и поддержки хранимых процедур
5. Несложно реализовать паттерн "Repository"
6. Несложно реализовать паттерн "Unit of work"

Comment: 6. Несложно реализовать паттерн "Unit of work"

Comment: Справедливости ради нужно отметить, что провайдеры EF/linq2db и многих других ORM есть практически для всех распространённых СУБД. Repository и UoW по сути уже реализованы DbContext'ом.

Answer (score 1):

Для таких целей существует [ClickHouse](https://clickhouse.yandex), который как раз таки был создан для работы с большим количеством данных, где играет роль скорость выборки и скорость записи, но не скорость удаления или обновления. [Ссылка на GitHub](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse) и [ссылка на Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickHouse)